# How do i subclass Django CreateView

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a model, for which i want to pass some arguments to the form.
the model is :

```
class CandidateNote(models.Model):
    candidate   = models.ForeignKey(CandProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='candidatenotes_cand')
    note_by     = models.ForeignKey(BaseUser, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='candidatenotes_user')
    job_note    = models.TextField(max_length=3000)
    date_added  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

As you can see the model has 2 Foreign keys (candidate and note_by)

On the form i will only be displaying the field '`job_note`'
the '`candidate`' and '`note_by`' fields will be populated by the view

```
class CreateNoteView(CreateView):

    template_name = 'candidates/create_note.html' 
    form_class = CreateNoteForm    
    success_url = reverse_lazy('staff_main')
```

I have been instructed that it is OK, to use the Generic `CreateView`, but that i will have to '`subclass`' the '`get_form()`' method and tack on the following:

```
form = CreateNoteForm(...); 
form.instance.candidate = self.object; 
form.instance.note_by = self.request.user; 
form.save()
```

I have looked at the default '`get_form()`' method in the `CreateView` class and it has :

```
def get_form(self, form_class=None):
    """Return an instance of the form to be used in this view."""
    if form_class is None:
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
    return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())
```

How on earth do i '`subclass`' and tack on

```
    form = CreateNoteForm(...);  
    form.instance.candidate = self.object; 
    form.instance.note_by = self.request.user; 
    form.save()
```

to the '`get_form`' method, and what do i put in the... part of :

```
form = CreateNoteForm(...);
```

and should i really `form.save()` at this point in my view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to call the `super` command on the generic view's `get_form` method, like so:

```
class CreateNoteView(CreateView):
    ...
    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        # Python 2.7-style super command:
        form = super(CreateNoteView, self).get_form(form_class)

        # If using Python 3, you would do this instead:
        # form = super().get_form(form_class)

        # begin the code that you wish to tack on:
        form.instance.candidate = self.object; 
        form.instance.note_by = self.request.user; 
        form.save()

        # Return the form variable, just like the parent class's get_form method:
        return form
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped a LOT with understanding how to subclass, it worked, except for the form_valid does the save() .